# Can I make a DIY developing tank from an opaque Tetrapak milk container?

Tags: diy, developing, large-format

I'm starting to home-develop ! I already have the daylight tank and the reels for medium format, but here I'd like to develop 4x5 emulsion films. What do I have at home that is light-tight and has the right format?

Tetrapak milk containers!

Has anybody tried it? My main question here is: would the chemicals react with the Tetrapak's inner coating?

Comment: Thanks for the edits guys and sorry as I'm French I'm making some recurrent mistakes in my English.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I recently started developing my 4x5 in this tank and I can't praise it enough. https://shop.stearmanpress.com/products/sp-445-compact-4x5-film-processing-system

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with a homemade tank? 4x5 sheet film is easy. All you need is plastic trays just large enough to accommodate. Procure 5 plastic or glass trays. If you shop in a kitchen store you will find them. I use a pre-soak with water. In total darkness submerge each sheet, one-by-one in the water bath. After the lot has thoroughly wet, transfer the stack to the developer tray. Your agitation pattern is to take the bottom sheet place it on top. Keep repeating this shuffling procedure until the developing time is up. Transfer the lot to the stop bath. Shuffle as before. Now immerse the stack in the fix and shuffle as before. Now turn on the lights. After the fix, wash in running water. It’s easy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually the problem here is that I live in a very small place with my two children messing around... But I'm considering building something in my changing bag... Like the Portable processing box of Joe Van Cleave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rJxA5UXCJw